# Coverage is skipping return statements

Tags: python, django, testing, nose

I have a class and some tests for it. Coverage runs everything just fine, but reports that the lines containing `return` are not executed. The rest of the multi-line return statement is executed just fine, just not the return itself.

Class:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            f'Name: {self.name}\n'
            f'Status: {self.status}\n'
        )

    def render_html(self):
        return (
            f'Name: {escape(self.name)}<br/>'
            f'Status: {escape(self.status)}<br/>'
        )
```

The test is calling both `render_html` and `__str__`. I'm using Django and running with `coverage run --branch ./manage.py test`

EDIT: I have another test later in the same file that has a simple `return somestring` that also isn't being run, so it's not the formatting of the multi-line strings.

Comment: They aren't tuples, it's a way to create multi-line strings. There are no errors or strange warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by installing `django_nose` and running with `python manage.py test --with-coverage --cover-package=app`.

I'm not entirely sure why running `coverage` directly gives incorrect results, but I assume it's because of something weird within Django that `django_nose` understands.